# Prove $H$ is isomorphic to $D_6$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

Let
$$H= \left\{\left.\begin{bmatrix} a & x  \\ 0 & b \end{bmatrix} \right| a,b \in (\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})^{\times}, x \in \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z} \right\} \leq GL_2(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}).$$
Show that $H \cong D_6$, the group of symmetries of a regular hexagon.

I started by showing that they are both of order $12$. I also know that I have to show that there is a homomorpshism and that it is bijective but I'm not sure how to find this.

Comment: We usually use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format math on this site. It looks better than angle bracket tagging.

Comment: If you know what the groups of order 12 are up to isomorphism, you could also show that $H$ is nonabelian and has an element of order $6$ but no element of order $4$.

Comment: For a concrete approach, if you know that $D_6$ is generated by a rotation of order $6$ and a reflection, you can try and find corresponding elements in $H$ and map them to those generators of $D_6$. But you have to be careful, because if you choose the sole *rotation* of order $2$ (or its counterpart in $H$) instead of reflection, you'll only generate a cyclic group.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you a hint:

$\begin{bmatrix}-1&1\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}$ has order $6$. This will give you the rotations (by taking powers), now pick any of the remaining six, to use as a reflection.